# Can we set the eyepiece of a telescope not at its focal length, to get a larger magnification?

Tags: optics, telescopes

I know the magnification of a telescope is fo/fe.
But this equation is based on the setting that we put the eyepiece a focal length away from the real image of the objective.
Why does we form the final image at infinity?
Can we adjust the eyepiece, so that we can have a different magnification?
Can we have an even larger magnification than fo/fe?

Answer (score 1):

The eyepiece acts like a magnifying glass forming a virtual image of the intermediate image produced by the objective

If the intermediate image is placed between the focus of the eyepiece and the eyepiece itself a larger magnification is produced being a maximum when the final virtual image produced by the eyepiece is at the near point of the eye.

Such an arrangement puts a strain on the eye as compared with having the final image at infinity when the eye is relaxed.

Comment: So... you could theoretically do so for a slight magnification boost with the cost being straining the eye with some additional focussing work?